# provide two docker images from the same dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am setting an automatic build from which I would like to produce 2 images.

The use-case is in building and distributing a library:
 - one image with the dependencies which will be reused for building and testing on Travis
 - one image to provide the built software libs

Basically, I need to be able to push an image of the container at a certain point (before building) and one later (after building and installing).

Is this possible? I did not find anything relevant in Dockerfile docs.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible without workarounds. You might be interested in the discussion about [adding a TAG command to Dockerfiles](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5603), where in the end it was decided to not implement that feature.

Comment: thanks for the reference. The proposed solution from Tarun does the trick in my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using Docker Multi Stage builds. Have two Docker files

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add gcc
RUN echo "This is a test" > /tmp/builtfile
```

**Dockerfile-prod**

```
FROM myapp:testing as source

FROM alpine
COPY --from=source /tmp/builtfile /tmp/builtfile
RUN cat /tmp/builtfile
```

**build.sh**

```
docker build -t myapp:testing .
docker build -t myapp:production -f Dockerfile-prod .
```

So to explain, what we do is build the image with dependencies first. Then in our second `Dockerfile-prod`, we just include a FROM of our previously build image. And copy the built file to the production image.

Truncated output from my build

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/so$ ./build.sh
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine
Step 2/3 : RUN apk update && apk add gcc
Step 3/3 : RUN echo "This is a test" > /tmp/builtfile
Successfully tagged myapp:testing

Step 1/4 : FROM myapp:testing as source
Step 2/4 : FROM alpine
Step 3/4 : COPY --from=source /tmp/builtfile /tmp/builtfile
Step 4/4 : RUN cat /tmp/builtfile
This is a test
Successfully tagged myapp:production
```

For more information refer to https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/#name-your-build-stages